# Requirements to enforce TLS 1.2

Tags: .net, azure, tls1.2

Application is hosted on Azure PAAS. The following changes are already present

1. Azure app services TLS is set to 1.2, HTTPSOnly is set to off
2. Service web config httpRuntime targetFramework is set to 4.7.1

What else changes do I need to do to ensure incoming and outgoing requests of my application adhere to TLS 1
2.

Comment: I think it should fix the issues. Still you should check your site with some tool like - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for this.

Comment: As of I know, that's it. One thing I would add is (though it may not relevant to the question), Never specify the TLS version in your application. Configure your code to let the OS decide the TLS version.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting June 30 2018, all new apps in Azure App Service will be created with **TLS 1.2 by default**.

In the root of the website, find the `global.asax` file, right click on it and view code. In this file, there should be an `Application_Start` method.

In this method, add these lines to force TLS 1.2

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //**Add these lines**
    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
    {
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    }
    //**Add these lines**

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Also, you could enforce TLS version on Azure WebApps with [Resource Manager Policies](https://cmatskas.com/enforcing-tls-version-on-azure-webapps-with-resource-manager-policies/).